# WPF: Could not create a instance of type

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this problem so that I can see nothing during WPF design.

Here is the WPF code at the begging:

```
<UserControl x:Class="VolumeControlInterface.VolumeControlInterface"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vtkVC="clr-namespace:VtkVolumeControl;assembly=VtkVolumeControl"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VolumeControlInterface"
    Height="700" Width="700" Margin="5"
```

Here is my WPF code wiggled underneath:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
    <vtkVC:VolumeRenderer Name="VolumeControl" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0"
        LowerThresholdChanA="{Binding Path=BlackPoint0, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        UpperThresholdChanA="{Binding Path=WhitePoint0, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        LowerThresholdChanB="{Binding Path=BlackPoint1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        UpperThresholdChanB="{Binding Path=WhitePoint1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        LowerThresholdChanC="{Binding Path=BlackPoint2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        UpperThresholdChanC="{Binding Path=WhitePoint2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        LowerThresholdChanD="{Binding Path=BlackPoint3, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        UpperThresholdChanD="{Binding Path=WhitePoint3, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        IsChanASelected="{Binding Path=IsChanASelected, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        IsChanBSelected="{Binding Path=IsChanBSelected, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        IsChanCSelected="{Binding Path=IsChanCSelected, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        IsChanDSelected="{Binding Path=IsChanDSelected, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        DataSpacingZ="{Binding Path=DataSpacingZ, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        DataSpacingZMultiplier="{Binding Path=DataSpacingZMultiplier, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        FolderDirectory="{Binding Path=ZStackCacheDirectory, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        HardwareSettingsFile="{Binding Path=HardwareSettingsFile, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        TileIndex="{Binding Path=TileIndex, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        WellIndex="{Binding Path=WellIndex, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        TimePointIndex="{Binding Path=TimePointIndex, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        TotalSystemChannels="4"
        Timepoints="1">
    </vtkVC:VolumeRenderer>
</Grid>
```

This project is `VolumeControlInterface`, which imports `VtkVolumeControl.dll` as reference from another project. `VolumeRenderer` is a class in `VtkVolumeControl`. The `VtkVolumeControl` is built successfully and the whole project functions with no problem. It is just I cannot see anything during design of `VolumeControlInterface`, and it says "Could not create a instance of type 'VolumeRender'"

**I have tried:**

Remove `VtkVolumeControl`, and re-add it. Not working.

Using `if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))` in the constructor, not working either.

I am wondering what is going on here, and how I should make the design visible?

**EDIT:
I am using VS2008, WINDOWS 7 64BIT**

Also, every time I build `vtkVolumeControl.dll`, the reference in `VolumeControlInterface` will show a warning, says cannot find the vtkVolumeControl.dll; But if I go ahead build `VolumeControlInterface` regardless, it won't have any problem, and it seems to manage to find `vtkVolumeControl.dll`.

**EDIT:**
This is how it looks:
[image]

Comment: maybe some designtime data.....check out this article for example - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/sample-data-in-the-wpf-and-silverlight-designer.aspx

Comment: Is that possible that some of the VS patches I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to achieve with the following line?

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
```

because you are using the UserControl as Binding, which I assume is not what you want.
try the following to access the datacontext of the `UserControl`

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems it gives the same error. Still cannot create VolumeRender. xaml does not display.

Comment: can you post the complete exception with stack and look for an inner exception?

Comment: Sure, but where to find the complete exception?